# Best way to deploy multiple preconfigured VMs to AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm just looking for advice, I can do most of my own research, but I'm not sure where to start. Here's the situation:

I want to be able to deploy 3 vms that have 2 nic's a piece. 1 nic will have a standard IP that AWS provides. The second nic will have a pre-configured internal static IP. Let's say, 192.168.0.100, 101, and 102. That way each vm can talk to each other automatically without needing to know what the external IP is. The purpose of this is so that I can have a small cluster already configured and I won't have to do a lot of work every time I deploy the cluster.

I want this to be repeatable. Let's say I want this for a classroom. Each student has the identical set of clustered VMs. All they need to do is power them on and start working.

So, I think I can do this with Terreform. I don't know if AWS has it's own tooling that can do this also. If it has, I haven't been able to find it yet.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cloudformation is an AWS infrastructure as code that you can use like terraform

Comment: Do you know if it can provide the functionality that I am looking for?

Comment: Yes, in this link you can find a lot of examples: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ec2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, every VM gets a private IP, if the VM is public you can assign a public IP which makes the VM accessible from external and also provides internet access, this is be done by source/destination NAT.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

As long as they are part of you VPC CIDR and available you can specify the IP addresses on instance launch. This can be done via AWS Console, API, CLI, CloudFormation and also with Terraform. The AWS native tools for doing it at scale / repeatable is CloudFormation or maybe also a script that runs AWS CLI commands would work.

- https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/opsworks/create-instance.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-network-interface-privateipspec.html